# Solving for the range of lengths of a irregular quadrilateral given two sides of equal (unspecified) length and one fixed side.

Tags: geometry

Given an irregular Quadrilateral with two opposing sides of length called constant *D*, one side fixed as 74 units, and another with length equal to 10x-4, find the range of possible values for x.

The problem is question is merely for algebra one, it is unlikely the techniques involved are anything more than simple geometry. However, I find myself stuck with it.

Methods tried:

I have split the Quadrilateral into two triangles that share a hypotenuse *H* and one leg of length *D*

Using Triangle inequalities I can gather two equations for each of the two triangles:

D > H - 74

And

D < H + (10x + 4)

Solving the two leaves me with a single bound for X, that is:

X > -7

Obviously this is not helpful, as the length of one side of the triangle must be greater than 0. When I realized this, I instead solved for

10x - 4 > 0

x > 4/10

But how might I find the upper bound on X?

Comment: For future reference, only a right triangle has a hypotenuse. Your two triangles will not generally be right triangles.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the side length of $74$ being "fixed" in space, with the vertices of the two sides of length $D$ away from the $74$ side moving apart as much as they can, such as indicated in the diagram below.

[image: Irregular quadrilateral example with 10x - 4 side at its maximum length]

This shows the upper limit for the length of the $10x - 4$ side would occur where the sides of length $D$, $74$ and $D$ are almost in a straight line, so the sum of their lengths would just barely be more than $10x - 4$. In that case, you get

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
D + 74 + D & \gt 10x - 4 \\
2D + 78 & \gt 10x \\
0.2(D) + 7.8 & \gt x
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

As for the lower limit, consider instead the vertices of the two sides of length $D$ away from the side length of $74$ moving together until they can touch, which occurs if $2D \ge 74$ and in which case you get $0.4 \lt x$ which you determined yourself, or until they basically almost reach the side of length $74$. In that latter case, as indicated in the diagram below,

[image: Irregular quadrilateral example with 10x - 4 side at its minimum length where the 2 sides of length D are not long enough]

the minimum length of the remaining side must be more than the difference of lengths, i.e., $74 - 2D$. Thus, consider

$$E = \max(0, 74 - 2D) \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

The more general lower limit would then come from

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
10x - 4 & \gt E \\
10x & \gt E + 4 \\
x & \gt 0.1(E) + 0.4
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

Thus, you then have

$$0.1(E) + 0.4 \lt x \lt 0.2(D) + 7.8 \tag{4}\label{eq4A}$$

as the possible range for $x$.